# Understanding PowerShell Comparators

Tags: powershell

I have a csv that contains a lot of columns, one of which is email.
When I try to search the CSV to see if it contains the specified email address, only the -like operator returns true.

Help me understand why "-in" and "-contains" won't work in this scenario?

```
$path = import-csv -path "C:\temp\file.csv"
$email = "*John.Doe@company.com*"

if ($path -like $email){
    write-host "LIKE"
}
if ($email -in $path){
    write-host "IN"
}
if ($path -contains $email){
    write-host "CONTAINS"
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `contains` and `in`? Did it answer your question? If not, what did you find confusing?

Comment: Yes I've read documentation, my scenario should work based on such, but it returns false.

Comment: For the comparison with `-in` and `-contains` to work properly it has to be a *perfect* match - no wildcards allowed.  If the email address in your CSV file is `John.Doe@company.com` you should use `$email = "John.Doe@company.com"` to get the result you probably expect.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. There is an email column with EXACTLY ```John.Doe@company.com```, and removing the wildcards from the script didn't change the results, but if it's looking for a perfect match, that may be the issue with things like case sensitivity or some weird UTF-8 shennanigans. Thanks!

Comment: PowerShell is by default case insensitive. If your CSV has headers you have to use them ... `if ($path.email -contains $email){` .... or  `if ($email -in $path.email){`

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing a CSV with multiple columns, like for example Name, and Email, you need to tell powershell first which column it is your looking for:

```
$path.Email -contains $email
```